# Opera default page - website links with logo

Tags: html, css, browser, opera, opera-blink

The default page on Opera Blink contains links to user-favourited webpages. Some of these webpages, like facebook, twitter, etc., have a logo.

When I add my website there, it doesn't show any logo; it shows only my-site.com text.

[image]

I see there are some websites which, when I add them here, display their logo.

What should I do with my website to make the logo retrievable by Opera?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### List of Favicon Sizes - Please see the update below...

Perhaps the correctly sized Favicon is missing? The size can vary by device.
Here is a great Favicon generator that will help you create the images and code. http://realfavicongenerator.net/ Its created by philippe_b, a contributor on Stack Overflow.

You'll need several sizes for the different devices and platforms. Here's a great article explaining the details: http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/understand-the-favicon/

Once you create the Favicon images, the links will go in the head of your html page.
Here's a good list to get you started...

```
<!--_________Start Favicons____________-->
<!-- favicon for non-IE browsers -->
<link rel="icon" href="media/img-icon/favicon.png">
<!-- favicon ico for IE only, IE doesn't recognize .png. E10+ won't see conditional comments, so favicon.ico was added to the root folder. Safari and Chrome will choose ico over png, so the conditional comment will hide the ico code from Safari and Chrome. -->
<!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="media/img-icon/favicon.ico"><![endif]-->
<!-- favicon Windows 8 Pinned Tiles. Application name = Tile text. Otherwise, it pulls from the title tag. TileColor = bg color -->
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="media/img-icon/windows-tile-144.png">
<meta name="application-name" content=“Name of Your Site”>
<!-- favicon Web Clips for Apple -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="media/img-icon/touch-icon-ipad.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="media/img-icon/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="media/img-icon/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="media/img-icon/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="media/img-icon/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="media/img-icon/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="media/img-icon/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="media/img-icon/touch-icon-iphone.png"> <!-- 57x57, smallest size listed last for older browsers -->
<!-- size and order are important for diffrent browser/browser functions-->
<link rel="icon" href="media/img-icon/favicon-16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" href="media/img-icon/favicon-48.png" sizes="48x48">
<link rel="icon" href="media/img-icon/favicon-64.png" sizes="64x64">
<link rel="icon" href="media/img-icon/favicon-128.png" sizes="128x128">
<link rel="icon" href="media/img-icon/favicon-32.png" sizes="32x32">
```

---

**Update**

Opera uses the larger icons. For the old Speed Dial, the Favicon had to be at least 114px x 114px, and anything smaller would not show. If you have a properly linked large Favicon, then it may be Opera's cache. Sometimes its difficult to see an updated Favicon because of the browsers cache. Once you add the Favicon, you may need to delete the bookmark, close the browser and re-bookmark your site to see the icon.

Using the Favicon set above:

1. Opera 12 displays the Favicon on the Speed Dial page. If only a small, or standard Favicon .ico is used, it displays a screenshot of the page instead.
2. Opera 25 also displays the correct Favicon, and it looks great. On the sites that have only the .ico file or a small icon, it will display the website text link as you pictured in your example.

So it looks like both versions use the larger Favicons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a favicon. The image which appears on the opera default page is not the favicon.

Comment: The OP is asking about a feature of Opera Blink (version 15+, from 2013 onwards, the speed dial has actually been changed in version 25); the articles you're quoting from 2011 are for the old Opera Presto. (It would probably help if the "opera" tag were split in two to avoid this type of confusion...) Having said that, it may still (or again) be the case that favicons are used as the new speed dial icons.

Comment: @Amos M. Carpenter - +1 for the helpful explanation. The older links were deleted to reflect the correction. The larger Favicon set, as described in the answer, displayed well in both Opera 12, and Opera 25. If the standard small icon was used, it showed a screenshot in 12, and a default text website link in 25.

Comment: +1 for the updated answer. :-) Also, for anyone interested who still uses Opera 12 (I do sometimes, mainly for Dragonfly and the awesome customisability, though I'm gradually switching), note that you can "force" the screenshot-type image by right-clicking the speed dial entry and setting the "Reload every..." value to one of the first few entries (e.g. 1 hour), then doing a "Reload", then setting it back to reload "Never". Sadly, these options don't exist in the new Opera (yet?).

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Talkingrock . Thank you #Amos M. Carpenter, too